# Inflate deflated data in javascript client side

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is server side java deflated method. I want to inflate the defalted data in javascript on client side.

```
private void deflate(String message){
byte[] input = message.getBytes("UTF-8");
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
Deflater compresser = new Deflater(Deflater.BEST_COMPRESSION);
compresser.setInput(input);
compresser.finish();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];  
while (!compresser.finished()) 
{ 
    int count = compresser.deflate(buffer);
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, count);  
} 
try {
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    log.debug(e.toString());
} 
output = outputStream.toByteArray(); 
compresser.end();}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. Can i use base64 to compress data in java side and uncompress data in javascript side.

Comment: Base64 has nothing to do with compression. You need base64 to encode binary data

Comment: Can anyone suggest me which modules are used to compress json data in java side and decompress json data in javascript.

Comment: @Balu Serve json with gzip compression. The browser will decompress it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our server side implementation of deflate uses ***ZLIB*** compression library, here is the java script implementation of the inflate of deflated data.

Library used [ZLIB](https://github.com/imaya/zlib.js/blob/master/README.en.md)

```
  var inflate = new Zlib.Inflate(compressed);
  var plain = inflate.decompress();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [Deflate implementation on JS](https://github.com/beatgammit/deflate-js) but I don't recomend it. Inflate on client side with JS isn't a very good idea. But the most important thing is you don't need the inflation routine in JS if you check the [compresion accepted on request (Accept-Encoding)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_compression), compress the JSON with that, and then set the appropiate response header (Content-Encoding).

Answer (score 0):

```
var zipString = ''
var zlib = require('zlib')
var {Buffer} = require('buffer')
const buff = Buffer.from(zipString, 'base64');
console.log('传给服务端的base64：', zipString)
zlib.inflate(buff, (err, buffer) => { 
    var unzipString = buffer.toString('utf8'); 
    console.log('解压缩的数据: ',unzipString)
    zlib.deflate(unzipString, (err, buffer) => { 
        console.log('重新进行压缩：', buffer)
        const base64 = buffer.toString('base64');
        console.log('重新压缩后传给服务端的base64（经检验服务端可以解压）：', base64);
    });
});
```